Forward rate from Covered Interest Parity when spot date is after expiry date
I am using Covered Interest Parity to impute a forward rate. The Webpage https://osf.io/ez6an describes how to calculate the forward rate from discount factors and spot rate. Normally, the spot date precedes the expiry date of the forward. However, the expiry date may precede the spot date when there are holidays. Why is the equation for calculating the forward rate different when the expiry date precedes the spot date?

I am trying to impute forward rates for the currency VND (VIETNAMESE DONG). The relevant data is as follows:

Tenor - 1W
Trade date - 2011-01-28
Spot date - 2011-02-09
Expiry date (Fixing date) - 2011-02-08
Delivery date - 2011-02-10.

The spot date is greatly delayed because of Lunar New Year holidays which are from 2011-01-31 to 2011-02-07.
The discount factor for the non-deliverable currency VND would normally run from the spot date to the fixing date. But here the fixing date 2011-02-08 precedes the spot date 2011-02-09.

Do you have an example? Usually normal forwards (what BBG shows on FRD after spot) are always after spot, because the tenor starts counting after spot settlement.

I have edited the question and provided relevant data.

The formula described is:
$$ f_t = f_s \frac{D_b(s,t)}{D_q(s,t)}$$
Where $D_b(s,t)$ and $D_q(s,t)$ are unhelpfully labelled as the discount factors from one date to the next. If you instead label these as discount factors at a particular date as measured from today, where today's discount factor is precisiely 1.0 then:
$$D_b(s,t) = \frac{D_b(t)}{D_b(s)}, \quad D_q(s,t) = \frac{D_q(t)}{D_q(s)} $$
The formula for a forward date that precedes spot does not change.
You only have to observe that the author flips the direction; $D_b(T_s, T) \; -> D_b(T, T_s)$ and then he also flips the quotient, resulting in the same formula.
